# Start app with angular-cli is too slow

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I come from angular 1 and my app used to load very fast. Now the start time is much longer. On phone, it's 5 - 10 seconds. The app is generated from angular-cli. Ng launch after ng build.  Is this normal? How can I built my app using AoT even if ng-cli does support it. Will it accelerate in AoT or not?

Comment: are you using ng-cli over Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Try `ng build --prod`. It concatenates angular files.

In `dev` each single file is received through a single request, which take enormous amount of time.

Comment: I did already this and with ng build all files are concated too, i wonder if with AoT it will fast

Comment: Does the `--prod` flag also minify the code as well?

Comment: Cool! Great to know and also another way to boost performance a little bit

Comment: Not sure it change a lot maybe AoT change but i donlt know how schieve this AoT compilation with angular-cli is there tips?

Comment: Seems like we are not there yet https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1732